# How to align row with background color with CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the style like this:

[image]

With my code I achieved like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <a class="appointments" data-ng-click="showPrev(index)">
        <i class="icon-double-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;
    </a>{{date}}
    <a data-ng-click="showNext(index)">
        <i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
    <div>
        <span class="appointments"  data-ng-repeat="time in times"><br>
        <span data-ng-click="showModal()">{{time}}</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please suggest me help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this help you to go in right direction...
Check the `CSS`

```css
.time > span {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  color: #2AAAC7;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  margin: -5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.date > i {
 color: #2AAAC7;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <a class="appointments date" data-ng-click="showPrev(index)">
  <i class="icon-double-angle-left"></i>&nbsp;
 </a>
  2017-06-29
 <a data-ng-click="showNext(index)">&nbsp;
  <i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>
 </a>
  
 <div>
  <span class="appointments time" data-ng-repeat="time in times"><br>
   <span data-ng-click="showModal()">8:00 AM</span>
  </span>
    <span class="appointments time" data-ng-repeat="time in times"><br>
   <span data-ng-click="showModal()">9:50 AM</span>
  </span>
    <span class="appointments time" data-ng-repeat="time in times"><br>
   <span data-ng-click="showModal()">10:00 AM</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding for the problem `padding-top`

Answer (score 0):

using css then you can solve your problem.

```
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
```

[1] [https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_striped]
[1]: refer for more informtion